How to optimize Django autoreload / startup process?
I am currently working on a very large Django project that includes many files and, more importantly, a substantial set of dependencies, including packages like Torch and Transformers.
Since installing Torch, I have noticed that the autoreload feature and the entire startup process when using the development server have become very slow. It now takes 10-15 seconds before I can test my code, which is quite frustrating during development.
Is there any way to optimize this process, such as telling Django to ignore certain imports or indexing when in DEBUG mode, or any other methods to speed up the autoreload and startup of the Django development server?

some points you can use to optimize process:

Use runserver_plus from Django Extensions:


The runserver_plus command from the django-extensions package provides enhanced development server features and may offer better performance in some scenarios.


Install with pip : pip install django-extensions


To start server with : python manage.py runserver_plus

2. Optimize Imports:

Optimize your imports to delay heavy imports like Torch until they are actually needed, instead of importing them at the top of your modules. This can help reduce the initial startup time.

def some_function():

    import torch

    # Your code


Will moving imports inside functions slow down their execution?
